# Why doesn't `lsvirtualenv` show my virtual environments?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I installed virtualwrapper using [the instruction](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), i.e. after installing via `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`, I got

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Documents/Devel
source /usr/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

listed in my `~/.zshrc` and `~/.profile` file, which I then sourced.

Then I created a virtual environment using `virtualenv env` in a folder. But when I run `lsvirtualenv`, nothing shows up. No message, just another `$` promt.

Why doesn't it show the newly created environment `env`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsvirtualenv` lists only virtual environments created in `$WORKON_HOME` using `mkvirtualenv`. Environments created elsewhere with `virtualenv` cannot be listed.

Once you started to use `virtualenvwrapper` you should constrain yourself with its commands without resorting back to `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess first determine if you have your env and wrapper [setup](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

next checkout this env [cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/bbengfort/246bc820e76b48f71df7) which goes over a few commands that achieve what your looking for.

hope that helps. If you found this useful please mark as answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the setup as instructed. The cheat sheet simply lists the commands I know. Maybe something missing in PATH?

Comment: seems to be making the most sense. Be sure to refresh your terminal or open a new window once env var is set.

Comment: Thanks. I reopened terminal, but no effect so far

Comment: could it be that you need to add the newly add env var to `PATH` so it's accessible system wide.